Elementor Media Upload Folder
By default, elementor has a “thumbs” folder for media present in posts. I want to set a limit on the no. of images this folder can have. So, that elementor should create a new folder for media of upcoming posts when the limit is reached/crossed.

That would be a fairly sophisticated thing to do; it's best to ask at https://elementor.com/help/ as theme-specific questions are off-topic here.

I also don't think you should do this - there's no benefit to it that I can think of.  Now you're just making elementor use multiple different paths to find it's 'thumbs'.
